# Neural Style Transfer Unsatisfactory Results

Tags: image, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, style-transfer

I am trying to use neural style transfer(NST) to visualize the results of remodelling of a home's interiors and how it will look as per the user's style image. While the code I use gives me good results most of the time, it occasionally gives me noisy and irrelevant results. What can be the cause of this phenomenon?

[image: This is an image where the NST has produced decent results and is able to transfer the stye quite well]

The above is an image where the NST has produced decent results and is able to transfer the stye quite well

[image: This is another situation where the NST process has failed terribly and is only outputting noisy results]

This is another situation where the NST process has failed terribly and is only outputting noisy results

Is there any technical name for this occurrence? Technical papers and articles on why this occurs and how to solve this will be greatly appreciated.